# A question on Koebe theorem

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Assume that $f$ is a conformal mapping of a bounded Jordan domain $\Omega$ onto the unit disk U such that $f(0)=0$. How to prove the following inequality 
$(1-|f(z)|)\le K \sqrt{dist(z,\partial \Omega)}$, where $K$ does not depend on $f$ but depends on distance of 0 from boundary of $\Omega$.

Comment: Why do you know that the inequality holds, if you don't know a proof?

Comment: Maybe you could ask your professor how to do the homework?

Comment: OK, guys, let me see YOU doing it just ONCE. Then I'll get convinced that you know what you are talking about when making such comments.

Comment: The inequality is used in a paper without any explanation. The inequality with a constant K_a where \Omega is C1 domain hold true in the inequality (1-|f(z)|) less than Kdist(0.\partial \Omega)^a, a <1. This is related to Brennan conjecture

Comment: @fedja I think Stefan's question is fair. I have moved martin's answer to a comment (which I think was meant as an answer to Stefan's question).

Answer (score 3):

I am also curious to know why you claim the inequality is true without knowing how to prove it. However, when I saw Fedja's challenge I wanted to try it myself :-) so here it goes :

I can prove the inequality
$$(1-|f(w)|)^2 \leq 4|f'(0)|(1+|f(w)|^2)dist(w,\partial \Omega).$$

First, recall the classical inequality for univalent functions on the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$ :

$$\frac{1}{4}(1-|z|^2)|f'(z)| \leq dist(f(z),\partial \Omega) \leq (1-|z|^2) |f'(z)|,$$
where $f$ is univalent on $\mathbb{D}$, $z \in \mathbb{D}$ and $\Omega = f(\mathbb{D})$.

The above inequality follows from Koebe's one-quarter theorem and Schwarz's lemma.

Applying the above with $f$ replaced by $f^{-1}$ and $z=f(w)$ yields
$$(1-|f(w)|^2) \leq \frac{4}{|(f^{-1})'(f(w))|} dist(w,\partial \Omega)$$
i.e.
$$(1-|f(w)|^2) \leq 4 |f'(w)| dist(w,\partial \Omega),$$
so that
$$(1-|f(w)|) \leq \frac{4|f'(w)|}{1+|f(w)|} dist(w,\partial \Omega).$$

Now, let us combine this with Koebe's distortion inequality :

$$\frac{|(f^{-1})'(z)|}{|(f^{-1})'(0)|} \geq \frac{1-|z|}{(1+|z|)^3}$$
for $z \in \mathbb{D}$.
Writing $z=f(w)$, we get
$$|f'(w)| \leq \frac{(1+|f(w)|)^3}{1-|f(w)|} |f'(0)|.$$
Combining this with the other inequality proves the claim.

You can bound the first factor by a constant depending only on $\Omega$ in the sense that you want. As in Eremenko's answer, you can bound $|f'(0)| \leq 1/R$ where $R$ is the distance from $0$ to $\partial \Omega$, so that we get
$$(1-|f(w)|)^2 \leq (8/R)dist(w,\partial \Omega).$$

Comment: In case martin's earlier answer was meant as a comment here, I'm copying it: "The inequality is used in a paper without any explanation. The inequality with a constant K_a where \Omega is C1 domain hold true in the inequality (1-|f(z)|) less than Kdist(0.\partial \Omega)^a, a <1. This is related to Brennan conjecture."

Answer (score 3):

Let $g$ be the inverse function to $f$, and $w=f(z)$, so that
$g(w)=z$. Let $h$ be the automorphism of the disc sending $0$ to $w$. Then
$g\circ h$ sends $0$ to $z$. Then by Koebe $1/4$ theorem
$$dist(g(w),\partial\Omega)\geq (1/4)|(g\circ h)'(0)|=(1/4)|g'(w)||h'(0)|.$$
We estimate $|g'(w)|$ by the Koebe distortion theorem which gives
$|g'(w)|\geq |g'(0)|(1-|w|)/8.$ Then we compute $|h'(0)|=1-|w|^2\geq 1-|w|$.
Finally we estimate $|g'(0)|$ from below using Schwarz's Lemma: 
$|g'(0)|=1/|f'(0)|\geq R$, where $R$ is the distance from $0$ to $\partial \Omega$.
Combining all these estimates, we obtain
$$dist(z,\partial\Omega)\geq (R/32)(1-|w|)^2.$$

Comment: @Eremenko i forgot to mention the depedence ok K on distance of 0 FROM the boundary of \Omega but certainly not on f

Comment: OK. You corrected your question and I changed my answer.